# Force constraint error in SQLite when using a rowid integer primary key

Tags: android, sqlite, constraints

I have created a table using the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL)
```

The problem I am having is that I can insert NULL for the `id` column despite the NOT NULL constraint. From what I understand, this is because the `id` column is now an alias for `rowid`.

If I change the data type of `id` to INT instead of INTEGER, the constraint works as I expect but I lose the `rowid` alias (and the benefits that come with it).

My question is: Is there a way to throw a constraint error when passing in NULL for a column that is an alias for `rowid`?

Comment: As per my comnent below. Does this work?:CREATE TABLE Person (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ON CONFLICT FAIL, name TEXT NOT NULL)

Comment: @IanWarwick, No unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: ok, its valid sqlite syntax but I guess since its an alias for rowid, then it will always have a non-null value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the short answer here is that there is no way to maintain the `rowid` alias while also preventing null insertions.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem I am having is that I can insert NULL for the id column despite the NOT NULL constraint.

If you try to insert `null` for an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` SQLite will silently use the next appropriate id.

SQLite conveniently interprets `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL`. So inserting a `null` id for the first row will create a row with the id of 1, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for this info but in regards to my question, is there a way I can instruct SQLite (perhaps some strict option) that would force SQLite to throw constraint errors instead of automatically choosing the next available row id when null is inserted.

Comment: Hmm, the easiest approach is to check the value of `id` in Java before attempting to insert the row. Otherwise you could create a new column to act _like_ the primary key column (and throw an exception for `NOT NULL`) or _maybe_ create a trigger to check `id` and cause a different constraint to fail... But those are both convoluted techniques, using Java is the simplest way.

Comment: Did you try using the ON CONFLICT FAIL clause on your NOT NULL constraint?

Comment: @Sam, I suppose java would be the way to go here. I wanted to avoid splitting my constraint checking so hopefully someone knows something I don't.